# There was an error reading the rules from the server

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Sometimes I get this error when I start Outlook:

[image]

Anyone know if it's an issue? Outlook otherwise starts and works normally after that.

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/56326/there-was-an-error-reading-the-rules-from-the-serv.html and 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/there-was-an-error-reading-the-rules-from-the/300fdbb3-f67a-4731-b40a-e519cc808953 and 
https://technoogies.com/outlook-error-reading-the-rules-from-the-server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of rules : Client/local, or server-side.

One or more rules on the Exchange server seem to be corrupted.

If you don't care about the server rules, you may remove them by running
the command
`OUTLOOK.EXE /cleanserverrules`.
You may also use the parameter `/cleanclientrules`, or even
`/cleanrules` to removes both sets of rules
(backup first the existing rules).

You could be more selective about server rules by logging
into `office.com` in the Outlook webapp and looking
at all the rules. You could then delete and recreate them one by one until
you find the corrupted rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could try below methods and check if this issue continues:

1. Recreate outlook profile.
2. Export the rules out to local file.(This method is provided by above [thread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/56326/there-was-an-error-reading-the-rules-from-the-serv.html).)

- Delete all the rules.
- Restart outlook.
- Open Rules again, if you see (client-only) rules again delete them
  all.
- Create any simple rule and save it.
- Restart Outlook.